# How to add a 5.1 .flac audio track to a .ts file with already 3 audio tracks?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I want to add a 5.1 .flac audio track to a .ts file that already has three audio tracks. I tried with tsMuxer and ffmpeg with unsuccessful results. In tsMuxeR the .flac track is not recognized and in ffmpeg everything seems to work fine until the very last moment when I check the file and the .flac audio track is not included in the "output.ts". The .flac track is about 3GB and its lenght is around two and a half hours.

Thank you so much.

Comment: ffmpeg can't mux flac in mpeg-ts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find any existing software that maps FLAC into a MPEG-2 Transport Stream.
This gives you an idea what sort of issues you run into: https://xiph.org/flac/ogg_mapping.html

Let's say you came up with a reasonable way of mapping FLAC into a MPEG-2 Transport Stream - there won't be anything reading it.

Unless there is a specified way of mapping FLAC into a MPEG-2 Tranport Stream - you are on your own.

But PCM is supported in a MPEG-2 Transport Stream (for example Blu-Ray).
I'd use ffmpeg to transcode your audio from FLAC to PCM and then mux it into your transport stream.
Your audio transcode (FLAC to PCM) is lossless.